# Angular: handle redirection to login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, authentication

I started with Angular and am totally lost.

For the beginning I call a simple Rest-GET request. The problem is, that the destination is behind a external login page. So my request gets redirected to the external page and my application fails.

What I want is to open this page I'm redirected to. And after the login was successful, I should be redirected to the first requested page (but this should be done by the external page, I guess).

The my code so far is not realy advanced but here it is:

```
var app = angular.module('webUI', [])
app.controller('Rest', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://test/rest/monitoring')
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.rest = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response){

            });
});
```

Is there a simple Angular function I miss, that would do what I'm looking for?

**Edit:**
Here is the error message I see in my browser console (Chrome->F12):

Redirect from 'https://test/rest/monitoring' to 'https://someExternalURL/internal/login?TYPE=somethingVeryLong' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your redirected url into successCallback function within $location.path('/someNewPath');.
You have to inject dependencies for $location into your controller.

```
      var app = angular.module('webUI', [])
      app.controller('Rest', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
          $http.get('https://test/rest/monitoring')
              .then(function successCallback(response) {
                  $scope.rest = response.data;
                  $location.path('/someNewPath');
              }, function errorCallback(response) {

              });
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But how do I get the URL I will redirect to. In my case '/someNewPath' is not always the same. Where can I extract the URL I'm redirected to?
Also, I tried your solution with just how you posted it, and expected a redirection to /someNewPath. All it did was adding "#/someNewPath" to my actual URL instead of redirecting somewhere. 
And that only worked after I added the line to my "errorCallback".
I edited my first post and added the error message from my browser console (Chrome -> F12)

Comment: you can use below line code in your App_Start folder webapiconfig.cs file.
HttpConfiguration config;
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular routing,
see why here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp
and here a good example https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld, once you config your routes you can do this:

```
var app = angular.module('webUI', [])
app.controller('Rest', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://test/rest/monitoring')
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.rest = response.data;
                $state.go('login');
            }, function errorCallback(response){

            });
});
```

Comment: I don't get how routing will help me, because it only seems to work on local resources. But if that would be possible, how could I get the URL I will be redirected to and use this in my routing rule? As far as I see, routing is based on fixed links and opens local resources.